# Websockets on localhost over https:// problems

Tags: ssl, https, websocket, certificate, localhost

I'm trying to write a service, my service is a WebsocketServer is written in nodejs, with express and the ws module. This service should be installed with node-webkit locally on a computer(on localhost) to communicate with a web site in https:// to exchange information. My problem is, that i need a trusted certificate for localhost(its not possible), because all browsers give a warning if i use a self signed certificate. I know i can ignore that warning, but in the future this software should be distribuited, and i dont want to give that warning for future clients. Is there a good way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the following options to work around this:

- Package your client-side interface as a [browser extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/skip-cert-error/)
- Setup a [Message Queue](https://pettigrew.rocks/2016/06/21/scaling-a-websocket-application-with-rabbitmq/) which transforms messages to your node server as Websocket requests
- Use a PAAS provider with [free certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html) to proxy to your domain

**References**

- [How do I use a self signed certificate for a HTTPS Node.js server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665863/1113772)
- [Simulating GitHub OAuth2 Login for Tests with JUnit, Webdriver & Hoverfly](https://opencredo.com/simulating-github-oauth2-login-junit-webdriver-hoverfly/)
- [Apache configuration using Self Signed Certificate - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q178Us0FQUc)
- [Amazon SES: Sendmail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sendmail.html)
- [SMTP Gateway Plugin for RabbitMQ](https://github.com/gotthardp/rabbitmq-email)
- [Sending RabbitMQ messages via websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862970/1113772)